# I can't access my website in xampp with other computer (same wifi)

Tags: php, web, networking, xampp, ip

**(using xampp )** 
i did it :
1- change port 80 to 8080
2- change serverName localhost to my ip
3- change to unable firewall in windows 10
4- and restart xampp

**but can't access website from other PC
 where is the problem?**

Comment: Try to disable firewall and check, Are you even able to ping the machine where application is hosted?

Comment: i did ping in other pc to my ip  but  ,i got it  message " Destination host unreachable"

Comment: did you tried disabling firewall of the machine where application is hosted?

Comment: yes disabled, my windows 10 and xampp v3.2.4

Comment: `Destination host unreachable` means that your host was unable to resolve the layer-3 to layer-2 address. That can be the case when the WAP is configured to not allow the clients of the WAP to communicate with each other. There is some type of problem using either ARP (IPv4) or NDP (IPv6) to resolve the layer-2 address from the layer-3 address. This is not a programming problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

May I know how your other pc to access your site?

By the intranet network, your site IP like 192.168.1.123

And your other pcs they are under same network and their IP like 192.168.1.124,125...

You can try to do:

Open the powershell of windows and ping/mtr/traceroute the others pc to check the connection OK or not each other, and ping yourself from those pc.

If both connections are not OK, please check is there security software or router blocked, then you need check them or ask your infra.

If both connections are OK, then we go to check the others pc:

Is there software like parent control to block browser access, and only access some sites.

How to ping, traceroute and mtr, here's a reference for you:

https://www.akliz.net/manage/knowledgebase/49/How-to-Use-Ping-Traceroute-and-MTR.html

And you can try the proxy tool 'ngrok' if all I said not work,

it is better tools for web developer to share localhost site to external user to access.

https://ngrok.com/